# Java TargetDataLine + AudioFormat vs frameSize + frameRate larger than 1 single sample

Tags: javasound

When calling AudioSystem.getLine(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat), does the AudioFormat frameSize and frameRate **have** to rigidly specify a frame size equal to exactly one sample, and a frameRate equal to the sampleRate?

The following code *works* (in the sense of "compiles and runs without errors"), but seems to be horribly inefficient because it's seemingly bothering my code every time it captures literally one single 2-byte sample:

```
AudioFormat format= new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 48000, 16, 1, 2, 48000, true);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
```

...but if I try to make each frame 10x larger, and reduce the framerate by the same amount, AudioSystem.getLine() returns null:

```
// causes AudioSystem.getLine() to return null
AudioFormat lessFrequent = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 48000, 16, 1, 20, 4800, true);
```

... and to be honest, I *really* want it to buffer even longer frames, and only bother me every 100ms:

```
// pure fantasy:
AudioFormat ideal = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 48000, 16, 1, 9600, 10, true);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this happening because present-day computers (like a 2023 Macbook Pro) no longer have soundcards capable of capturing to their own ram & automatically DMA'ing it periodically without bothering the CPU every step of the way... so now, framerate and sample rate now have to be identical?

#### Update:

Assuming many/most -- but not *all* -- computers require that framerate and framesize have values corresponding to "exactly one sample", is there any way (using the Java API) for a program to discover whether the current computer falls into that category, or whether it's able to capture audio with larger & less-frequent frames? And if it can... either the range(s) or exact values that it regards as acceptable? Or, are you/the user literally expected to just keep blindly stabbing in the dark trying different permutations until one of them finally returns a non-null TargetDataLine?

Comment: The frameSize is nothing to do with the buffer size, it is just the size of one sample * the number of channels. When you read from the audio stream you can use a much bigger buffer.

Comment: Well, the thing I'm trying to understand/clarify is why they'd make you specify *both* sampleRate *and* frameRate if they have to be equal *anyway*, and why they'd make you bother to explicitly specify frameSize if it's *always* going to be ((sampleSizeInBits / 8) * channels).

Comment: I don't know why it is designed like that, but for PCM data that is what you use. The code I use does that and reads data using 64k buffers.

Answer (score 0):

A buffer size isn't part of the class `AudioFormat`. But a buffer size can be specified for the `SourceDataLine` or `TargetDataLine`, the lines used for sending and receiving data, using the `.open()` method.

I haven't played around with the different `AudioFormat` constructors, have always just used [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html#%3Cinit%3E(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding,float,int,int,int,float,boolean)):

```
public AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding encoding,
    float sampleRate,
    int sampleSizeInBits,
    int channels,
    int frameSize,
    float frameRate,
    boolean bigEndian)
```

To keep things simple for myself, I stick with the standard "CD Quality" format:

```
encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED
sampleRate = 44100 
sampleSizeInBits = 16
channels = 2               // stereo
frameSize = 4              // 2 bytes per sample x 2 channels
frameRate = 44100          
bigEndian = false
```

I'm guessing that you have tools or external sources with audio data at 48000 fps.

In the API documentation for [AudioFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html), there are a number of other constructors. There is one which doesn't require the size in bytes of a single frame. The API description for `AudioFormat` also has definitions for all the variables & terms used.